# wordpressを使用する際のnginxの設定

Tags: wordpress, nginx

WordPressをnginxで動かしているのですが、固定ページの表示でハマってしまったので質問です。

以下（①）のnginx.conf（一部）から、

```
    location / {
        index index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

        location ~* /wp-config.php {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/wordpress/$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

以下（②）の設定に変更しました。

```
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @wordpress;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri @wordpress;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/wordpress$fastcgi_script_name;
        include       fastcgi_params;
    }

    location @wordpress {
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/wordpress/index.php;
        include       fastcgi_params;
    }
```

しかし、①の設定では固定ページが404で表示されず、②の設定ではTOPページやダッシュボードが403で表示されません。

nginx.confをどのように設定すれば全てのページが表示されるのかわからず、途方にくれています。
わかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/80594

Comment: マルチポスト先で解決済みの様子

Answer (score 1):

指定されたファイル、フォルダーを見つけられない時は、wordpressがインストールされているフォルダーのindex.phpへリダイレクトすればとりあえず固定ページを表示できます。
以下に設定例を書きますが、https://wpdocs.osdn.jp/Nginx　を読まれることをすすめます。

前提条件：nginx.confはデフォルト設定で　フォルダー　/wordpressにインストールされていてwordpressへログインできていて、パーマリンク設定は、数字ベースに変更している
環境での一番簡易な設定方法は

```
location / {
       index index.html index.php;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
}
```

> try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;

をルート定義に１行追加するればよいです。

上記で表示されたら①の定義を見直すと表示されるかもしれません。
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /usr/share/nginx/wordpress/$fastcgi_script_name;
で指定しているドキュメントルートパス(/usr/share/nginx/wordpress/)は誤りがありませんか？
include fastcgi_params;の中に、fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME が定義されていてSCRIPT_FILENAMEが上書きされているかもしれませんのでincludeの位置をfastcgi_index  index.php;の次に移したらどうでしょう。